# What is the highest value that can b input for an integer variable in c++ by a user?

Tags: c++, console-application, command-line-interface

So, I made a c++ program to calculate the volume of a pool. It is a console application. All the user has to do is input the dimensions of the pool and the program will return the volume, amount of water and the area of the pool.

The problem is that I tested out the program with really high numbers and for some reason it does not work anymore (it returns wrong negative values). So, I was wondering, are there any limitations for how big the inputted value can be for a variable in int?

Also, if I run the program in release mode once it makes the calculations it displays the answer for a split second and, than closes immediately. Is there a way to keep it open, so that the user has time to actually look at the answers?

Comment: Whoa whoa, you are asking two completely separate questions here, neither of which is complete according to our rules. Please read the following guide on how to ask a question on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Depends on your targets [numeric_limits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        char x;
        std::cout << INT_MAX << std::endl;
        std::cin.get();
}
```

This will output the max int value, and wait for the user to hit the return key before exiting.  Hopefully that will allow you to pause to read the answers in your program?

Comment: Thank you! By the way, why does the max value have to be displayed, why can it just be written down? Is it different for everybody for some reason? and would you mind telling me how I make the program wait for the user to hit the return key?

Comment: It can vary between architectures and devices. The std::cin.get() line waits for the user to hit the return key, it waits until it has read one character.

Comment: Oh, ok.Thank you so much!